# Code runs perfectly but ends with a segmentation fault after running

Tags: c++, c++98

I've determined that my remove function for removing nodes from a linked list is the problem, but I cant see why.

```
void LinkedList::remove(string license){
  moveToHead();
  while(currentPtr != NULL){
    if(getCurrent().get_licence() == license){
      if(currentPtr == headPtr){
        removeFromHead();
      }else if(currentPtr == tailPtr){
        removeFromTail();
      }else{
        currentPtr->getNext()->setPrev(currentPtr->getPrev());
        currentPtr->getPrev()->setNext(currentPtr->getNext());
        delete currentPtr;
        currentPtr = headPtr;
      }
    }
    forward();
    listLength--;
  }
  moveToHead();
}
```

`moveToHead()` moves my current pointer to head and `forward()` moves it to the next item on the list.

The code runs without issue, but I get a `segmentation fault (core dumped)` after it finishes running, rather than crashing when `remove()` is used

Comment: Did you tried a debugger?

Comment: *The code runs without issue* -- My car starts and drives, but it can't stop.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  You corrupted memory, but you were not aware of it until your program finally broke down at the end.  Similar to that car starting, driving, and when you tried to stop, everything finally broke down.

Comment: Your code has some design flaws, I suggest to reinvent your code. Especially don't use a pointer as a control instrument for a while loop. Also better use `case` instead of those `if...else` and make sure to use always a "safe" `default` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at the logic, you are calling `forward();` and `listLength--;` even if `if(getCurrent().get_licence() == license){` is true? Shouldn't you return if the correct `license` is found and removed?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```sh
g++ -fsanitize=address main.cpp
```

or a related variant to compile your code and then run it. This will tell you how you've misused memory to cause the segfault.